# how to assign parameter passed to constructor to local private variable with the same name

Tags: javascript, typescript

the question seems very primitive but i am new to javascript and vuejs. as shown in the code posted below,i am creating a class `DigitizePolygonInteractions` that extends `MapBuilder`. the constructor receives two parameters `moduleName` and `mapInstance`.

i want to assign the parameter `mapInstance` that is passed to the constructor to a local private variable named `mapInstance` as well. as for the code posted below, visual-studio codes does not highlight the `let mapInstance` when the following line of code
is added `this.mapInstance = mapInstance`, which indicates that `this.mapInstance` is not used.

in java, given the code posted below, for the statement `this.mapInstance = mapInstance`, `this.mapInstance` refers to `let mapInstance` while `mapInstance` refers to `mapInstance` that is passed to the constructor

how can i achieve the same in javascript please

**code**:

```
let instance;
let mapInstance //<==should be the local private variable

export class DigitizePolygonInteractions extends MapBuilder {
 /** 
 *  @param { string } moduleName like 'map-sen2bee'
 */
  constructor(moduleName,mapInstance) {
    super(moduleName);
    instance = this
    this.mapInstance = mapInstance //<==============here
```

}

Comment: Hi, when you say "local private variable named mapInstance", do you want it private to the class itself or you mean the whole module within which this class is declared?

Also, terminologies might be confusing when coming from lang like Java, because they might refer to different things in JS. So you can just tell what exactly do you intend to do.

Comment: @would you please provide an example for either options

Comment: Why does the question has typescript tag if you use JS? The convention is to use underscored names for private properties. Forcing the encapsulation for encapsulation's sake will result in problems, like the absence of reflection when you need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let instance;
let mapInstance;

export class DigitizePolygonInteractions extends MapBuilder {
  constructor(moduleName, _mapInstance) {
    super(moduleName);
    instance = this;
    mapInstance = _mapInstance;
  }
}
```

However, a better approach would be:

```
export class DigitizePolygonInteractions extends MapBuilder {
  constructor(moduleName, mapInstance) {
    super(moduleName);
    this.instance = this;
    this.mapInstance = mapInstance;
  }
}
```

Comment: would you please tell me, for the second code snippet you poested, what if ,instead of this.mapInstance, i declared mapInstance above `export class...` as `let mapInstance` ..what is the difference please

Comment: It's all about scope: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope @letsamrit and execution context. Scope is determined by where a variable is declared. Context is the state of the current execution of code.

Example #1 will keep moduleName and mapInstance outside of DigitizePolygonInteractions, while in #2 example both will be inside DigitizePolygonInteractions execution context.

Answer (score 1):

```
let instance;
let mapInstance // this variable will be scoped to the file or module.  


export class DigitizePolygonInteractions extends MapBuilder {
 /** 
 *  @param { string } moduleName like 'map-sen2bee'
 */
  constructor(moduleName, _mapInstance) {
    super(moduleName);
    instance = this
    this.mapInstance = _mapInstance; // this.mapInstance is a property on the object that this class will generate. 
    mapInstance  = _mapInstance; // mapInstance is a variable that exists outside this class. Basically it has nothing to do with this class.
    
   }
```

I haven't worked with classes that much, but I can try to explain it with a very simple example below;

```
let name;

class Person{
  constructor(_name, age){
    // 'this' here refers to the object that will be created when this class is instantiated (see below)
   this.name = _name;
   name = _name;
   this.age = age;  
} 
}

const boy1 = new Person('jack', 21);

console.log(boy1) // {name: 'jack', age: 21}
console.log(name) // jack
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the variables must be in the context of the class itself in order to access them via `this`. Unfortunately I am using typescript instead of pure javascript, but a working example in typescript would be:

```
let instance;

export class DigitizePolygonInteractions extends MapBuilder {

  private mapInstance: [Type] = {}; //<== is a local private variable of the class now and can be accessed via 'this'

  constructor(moduleName,mapInstance) {
    super(moduleName);
    instance = this
    this.mapInstance = mapInstance 
    ...
```